# Converting ASP.NET Web Form to HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm in the process of converting our existing ASP.NET web form pages to support HTML5.

According to several sources, all I need to do is change my aspx page so that it has the following layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>/title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the top part of the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyForm.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false"
    Inherits="MyForm" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body> 

<div> BLA BLA BLA </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, when the page is rendered in a browser, and I view the source of the page, I still see the old DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.....
```

Any idea how I can get rid of this?

Comment: What is in your MyForm.aspx.cs?

Comment: You've definitely got something screwy going on. ASP.NET doesn't just inject a DOCTYPE like that on its own. I'd look for something in a base form class, something in one of the Global event handlers, or a custom module or something like that. Side note though - HTML should be lower-case: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Joe Enos, you are correct! Was in base class.